# LINQ join multi tables in Lambda ex

Tags: linq, join, model-view-controller

I hope that someone can help me out here or to point me in the right direction:

I have an issue with this script from my SQL. This is what I have from the database and it comes out with success.

Script for water counter that has reminder for active period:

```
Select * 
from WaterCounters
join WaterUsages on WaterUsages.WaterCounterId = WaterCounters.Id
join Periodes per on per.PeriodeId=WaterUsages.PeriodeId
where per.IsApproved = 1
```

Now I am trying to "translate/convert" into a LINQ query:

```
var waterCounter = Context.MyWaterCounter.Join(xx).ToList...
```

I am sure that I am doing it right but please advice me in how to "join more than one table" - thanks in advance.

Best regards,

*Kvolle*

**UPDATED:**
this is my script so far:

```
var waterCounter = Context.MyWaterCounter.Join(
                        Context.MyWaterUsages
                   .Where(x => x.WaterCounterId ==x.WaterCounterId)
                   .ToList());
```

Here is as I see it one table.

The tables in the database look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also, tell what type of LINQ you're targeting (to entities?), and show your own first efforts so we see where *specifically* you need help. The best LINQ query is hardly ever a 1:1 reproduction of a SQL query.

Comment: @Gert I will update this issue in a min with the "things" you say... thanks mate:-)

Comment: So far you failed to give details on the ORM you're using. Whichever it is, you probably shouldn't join at all in LINQ, but use navigation properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will look something like below

```
var waterCounter = Context.MyWaterCounter.Join(
                        Context.MyWaterUsages,
                        (WC) => WC.WaterCounterId,
                        (WU) => WU.Id,
                        (WC, WU) => new { WaterCounter = WC, WaterUsage = WU}
                   )
                   .Join(
                        Context.Periodes.Where(p => p.IsApproved=1),
                        (WUC) => WUC.WaterUsage.PeriodeId,
                        (P) => P.PeriodeId,
                        (WUC, P) => new { WaterCounter = WUC.WaterCounter, WaterUsage = WUC.WaterUsage, Period = P}
                   )
                   .ToList());
```

Comment: thank YOU so much:-) I will try it out straight away:-)
I

Comment: Thanks it seems to be working :-) 
Have a nice day and good weekend:-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52327831/5852145
Somehow this is coming out with "no rows wheere there should be at least some "
Please help me to see what i am doing wrong..